# Does normal Riemann hypothesis follow from extended Riemann hypothesis

Tags: nt.number-theory

Does normal Riemann hypothesis for $\zeta_{\mathbb{Q}}$ follows from the extended Riemann hypothesis for some $K \neq \mathbb{Q}$ (i.e. the statement that all zeroes of the Dedekind zeta function $\zeta_K$ for $K$ a number field in the critical strip lie on the axis $\mathfrak{R}(s)=1/2$)?

Comment: Well, $\mathbb{Q}$ is a number field... 

Comment: Yes I mean if we know it is true for one $K \neq \mathbb{Q}$ does it follow for $\mathbb{Q}$?


Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, certainly: zeta functions of abelian extensions of $\mathbb Q$ factor as products of Dirichlet $L$-functions over $\mathbb Q$, including $\zeta(s)$, and those other $L$-functions have no poles (which might cancel an off-line zero of zeta), so RH for any abelian extension of $\mathbb Q$ implies that for $\mathbb Q$.

At this point in history, the fact that we do not know that *all* Artin $L$-functions lack poles in the critical strip severely complicates our provable understanding of an analogous assertion for not-abelian extensions.

Comment: Nonabelian *Galois* extensions still work. That is, if $L/K$ is a finite Galois extension of number fields, then $\zeta_L(s)/\zeta_K(s)$ is known to be analytic.